# Run multiple shell scripts sequentially using single cronjob

Tags: linux, unix, hadoop

There are 2 shell scripts, test.sh & execute.sh, I need to run both the shell scripts using single cron job. Once the test.sh has completed execution then I need to run execute.sh sequentially. execute.sh must not be triggered until test.sh has executed successfully. execute.sh takes one parameter i.e properties file /user/abc/config.properties. I need to run this every one hour recursively. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, a cron job like this would do:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/test.sh && /path/to/execute.sh /user/abc/config.properties
```